# Get a sibling div with specific class and is not disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find a div with a class associated with it, but it must not be disabled.
I am using following code for getting the next sibling, but it will return the next element with the "menuDiv" class.

```
var nextDiv=jQuery('div.subMenuBarhover').nextAll('.menuDiv:first');
```

but now I need the element which is not disable and id of all element is unkown.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is a disabled div? How do you indicate that it is (not) disabled?

Comment: There is not built-in disabled state for non-input elements. How do you check if your div is disabled, by a class or a custom attribute?

Comment: i'm using custom attribute disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are using a custom attribute to mark a `div` as disabled. I would recommend to always use `data-*` attributes for custom attributes, i.e.

```
<div data-disabled="true">
```

To select the next `div` without that attribute, use the [negation pseudo class (aka `:not` selector)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) and the *attribute* selector:

```
jQuery('div.subMenuBarhover').nextAll('.menuDiv:not([data-disabled]):first');
```

If you want to find the next element where the `data-disabled` attribute has a certain value, use the [*attribute-equals*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
jQuery('div.subMenuBarhover').nextAll('.menuDiv[data-disabled=false):first');
```

---

In general, [have a look at all the existing selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) have try them out!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .`not(':disabled')` to your code as required.

[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[disabled selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

Comment: I have tried to use nextDiv=jQuery('div.subMenuBarhover :not(:disabled)').nextAll('.menuDiv:first');
 but it was not working. So i was wondering where should .not() be added.